# could not convert string to float: astype(float)

Tags: pandas

I would like to convert the string to float in pandas

`df['BusinessTravel'] = df['BusinessTravel'].astype(float)`
but it gives me this error:
could not convert string to float: 'Travel_Rarely'

Does anybody know how to fix it?

Comment: If it is not a number, you cannot represent it as a float.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert something like this `pi_string = "3.1415926"` to float with `float(pi_string)` but to convert a string such as `BusinessTravel` is not possible.

What you can do is map your strings in dict object.

```
map_dict = {"Travel_Rarely" : 1.0,
             "Travel_Frequently" : 2.0,
             "Travel_Occasionaly" : 3.0 }
```

and then use it to map all existing values of `BusinessTravel` column.

(Hint: Use `apply` on the column)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I truly appreciate your help.